# Convert pcap <-> pcap-ng, pcap-ng tools/libraries

Tags: networking, wireshark, pcap, pcap-ng

I'm looking for some information about pcap-ng.

What is the difference between pcap-ng and pcap?

Is there any tool/library for pcap-ng?

How to convert pcap to pcap-ng and pcap-ng to pcap?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What is the difference between pcap-ng and pcap?

pcap is older and less capable than pcap-ng, but is simpler.  Here's [a description of pcap file format](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-savefile.5.html); here's [a description of pcap-ng file format](http://www.winpcap.org/ntar/draft/PCAP-DumpFileFormat.html).

> Is there any tool/library for pcap-ng?

Newer versions of libpcap can read some pcap-ng files (all interfaces need to have the same link-layer header type and snapshot length, as the libpcap API can supply only one link-layer header type and only one snapshot length for a file).  Wireshark includes a library that can read and write a number of capture file formats, including pcap and pcap-ng, but it doesn't have a stable or well-documented API (it'll be changed quite significantly in the next Wireshark major release to better support pcap-ng and other formats).

> How to convert pcap to pcap-ng and pcap-ng to pcap?

Use the "editcap" tool that comes with Wireshark.  Note that not all pcap-ng files can be converted to pcap files - only the files that could be read by libpcap can be converted (and those can also be converted from pcap-ng to pcap by tcpdump, if tcpdump is using a newer version of libpcap capable of reading pcap-ng files).

Answer (score 1):

> How to convert pcap to pcap-ng and pcap-ng to pcap?

**[Linux/Wireshark Easy Explanation]**

Guy Harris answered very well, but I will focus on the last question as I suppose that many (like me) are passed and will pass here in search of a simple explanation about convert pcapng to pcap (and viceversa).
As Guy mentioned, not all pcap-ng files can be converted to pcap files because editcap may not work, so just don't save your packets in pcapng format but in libcap.

> pcapng -> pcap

Save your captured packets in libcap format ([example](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/wsug_graphics/xws-save-as-win32.png.pagespeed.ic._cilg8Qtxq.png) - link refers to windows-sample but its the same in Linux)

Open a shell in the path of interest and use tcpdump in the following way

tcpdump -r *file_to_convert* -w *file_converted* 
(if you dont have tcpdump installed, just install it with "apt-get install tcpdump" or search google if you have a different Linux distribution)

> pcap -> pcapng

Open your pcap file with Wireshark and save it in pcapng format. You have done you conversion. 
Hope this can help as it helped me.

Comment: "Open your pcap file with Wireshark and save it in pcapng format." or do `editcap -F pcapng` *file_to_convert* *file_converted* on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

There is some good information about the benefits and drawbacks of using PCAP-NG compared to plain old PCAP over at [PcapNG.com](http://pcapng.com).

The main difference between the two formats is that PCAP-NG allows for multiple interface types and annotations (i.e. comments). PCAP-NG can also store name resolution blocks (i.e. cached hostname / DNS entries), which is a useful feature but also a privacy issue.

PcapNG.com additionally has an online conversion feature, which lets you convert any PCAP-NG file back to the PCAP format.